# Swf streaming on iPAD with Flash media server

Tags: ios, html, flash, flash-media-server

I have a swf file with dynamic data variables embedded in a  html page with swfobject.js. But this will not work on iPAD since its swf. If I move this swf to Flash media server (version 5.0) will this work via HLS streaming. We have a adobe media server of version 5.0. Will this work on iOS devices if I load this via FMS with dynamic data

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is designed to work on iPad. I tried StageVideo and HLS from FMS in the past.

http://www.overdigital.com/2012/01/14/720p-video-on-ipad-and-android-tablets-with-adobe-air/